# Execute System Bash Shell Initialization Script Last

Tags: bash, unix, operating-system

At login on my OS X system and most linux systems I've used after the system versions of profile and bashrc are executed the users bashrc and profile are then executed.  Suppose you want a certain shell script run on every login *after* the users shell initialization (e.g. to ensure a certain path is added to the front of the PATH) is there a good way to do this?  Note this isn't about forcing users to do anything but just about a good default so it's fine if they can override the behavior.

The natural thought that occured to me was to suppress default execution of the user initialization and instead call it from the system scripts but then it occured to me that there is some complex logic about when which scripts are executed that I might screw up.

Anyway, I figure this is a solved problem and I was surprised I didn't find a post already answering it (so if I missed it sorry).

Comment: is this what you are trying to do `/etc/profile -> /etc/bashrc -> ~/.bashrc -> a_custom_command` ?

Comment: but you want this order to be system-wide and applicable for all users, is my understanding right?